# Line counter in mismatch program

Tags: python

So I'm making a simple program that will compare two text files and print out if there is a mismatch, and on what row the mismatch is in.
But there is a problem, it seems to count wrong after a while, it's probably a simple explanation but I can't figure it out.

Below is the code:

```
from gooey import Gooey
from gooey import GooeyParser
import difflib


@Gooey(program_description="Compare two maintag files.")


def main():
    f1 = GooeyParser(description='First maintag.txt file')
    f1.add_argument('FirstMaintag', widget='FileChooser')
    f1.add_argument('SecondMaintag', widget='FileChooser')
    f1arg = f1.parse_args()
    with open(f1arg.FirstMaintag, 'r') as file1, open(f1arg.SecondMaintag, 'r') as file2:
        rowcounter = 0
        difference = difflib.Differ()

        for line in difference.compare(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines()):
            rowcounter += 1
            if '+' in line or '-' in line:
                print(f'There is a mismatch in row {rowcounter}: {line} doesnt compare in {f1arg.FirstMaintag}')
            else:
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output i get is:

```
There is a mismatch in row 4: + Linje5
 doesnt compare in C:\Users\haral\Desktop\Test.txt
There is a mismatch in row 6: - Linje5
 doesnt compare in C:\Users\haral\Desktop\Test.txt
There is a mismatch in row 15: - Linje7
 doesnt compare in C:\Users\haral\Desktop\Test.txt
There is a mismatch in row 17: - 
 doesnt compare in C:\Users\haral\Desktop\Test.txt
```

The two txt files have this code:
file1:

```
Linje1
Linje2
Linje3
Linje4
Linje5
Linje6
Linje7
Linje1
Linje2
Linje3
Linje4
Linje5
Linje6
Linje7
```

file2

```
Linje1
Linje2
Linje3
Linje5
Linje4
Linje6
Linje7
Linje1
Linje2
Linje3
Linje4
Linje5
Linje6
```

It finds the mismatch on line 4, but it then says it is a mismatch on line 6 when in reality it is on line 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting the number of lines in the comparison result, which does not equal the number of lines in either file. Example:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> for line in diff.compare(['one', 'two', 'three'], ['one', 'tow', 'three']):
...     n += 1
...     print(f'{n}: {line}')
...
1:   one
2: - two
3: + tow
4:   three
```

Comment: I can see now that diff.compare actually was two lines. I just added a n -= 1 for the if statement and it worked, thank you :)